# How to output terraform output file in Azure DevOps in release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How to output Terraform output file in Azure DevOps in release pipeline.
I am using Run Terraform task in Release pipeline. I have a output file in Repo which outputs public IPs.
I want to store it as Variable which can be used in further tasks.

Answer (score 4):

For this issue ,it can be done with a simple output and powershell script:

1.Specify the output variable from terraform task

[image]

2.Create a PowerShell step in your release and insert the following script:

```
$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}
```

This will automatically create a variable for every output provided by the `terraform` script.

Make sure you have provided the environment variable jsonPath like this:

[image]

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463677/pass-output-from-terraform-to-azure-devops-pipeline-with-state-file-in-azure-bac) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Hugh Lin - MSFT - what will the variables names be  in this case ?

Comment: The variable name is `$($prop.Name)`, which is defined in `setvariable`.

Comment: @Abhishek Singh If this solution is helpful to you,could you [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? To accept an answer, please click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons. Please view this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djo7d.png). This will help other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily . Have a nice day :)